Error en configuracion de servidor con NGINX
resulta que realice un proyecto en html, css, JavaScript, y también use Node.Js y Express.Js. El proyecto de manera local funciona perfectamente, pero cuando lo subo a un cloud server en DonWeb se me complico bastante configurarlo vía NGINX, cuando uso certbot para la comunicación con el cliente mediante certificados por Lets Encrypt, ya no me funciona el logeo ni nada ( me aparece en la url del navegador www.dominio.com/?password="contraseñaqueponga" ), y cuando lo pruebo de forma local me envia a formulario.html si pongo bien la contraseña. El server.js de esta en la ubicación
/var/www/www.dominioejemplo.com/certificados
El codigo en el NGINX que hice es el siguiente:
server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name dominio.com www.dominio.com;

        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/dominio.com/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/dominio.com/privkey.pem;
        include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
        ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;

        location /css/ {
                alias /var/www/www.dominio.com/certificados/produccion/CSS/;
        }

        location /img/ {
                alias /var/www/www.dominio.com/certificados/produccion/img/;
        }

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ @node;
        }

        location @node {
                 proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
                 proxy_set_header Host $host;
                 proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                 proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                 proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;     }


}
server {
    if ($host = www.dominio.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }


    if ($host = dominio.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }


        listen 80;
        server_name dominio.com www.dominio.com;
    return 404;
}

probe poniendo pimero el location @node pero da lo mismo, por ultimo pense que por ahi no manejaba correctamente los post en el server.js, aca muestro un ejemplo de como lo hago:
app.get('/formulario', (req, res) => {
    const password = req.query.password;
    if (password === process.env.PASSWORD) {
        res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'produccion', 'formulario.html'));
    } else {
        res.status(401).send('Acceso denegado');
    }
});

No estoy seguro si tendria que usar el metodo POST y ahi si me anda, desde ya muchas gracias!

El problema parece estar en el uso del método GET en lugar de POST para enviar la contraseña, lo cual expone la contraseña en la URL. Cambia la ruta /formulario para que use POST y ajusta el formulario en el HTML para que envíe la solicitud usando POST.
También asegúrate de que NGINX esté configurado para manejar correctamente las solicitudes POST.
Cambiar a POST en el servidor:
app.post('/formulario', (req, res) => {
    const password = req.body.password;
    if (password === process.env.PASSWORD) {
        res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'produccion', 'formulario.html'));
    } else {
        res.status(401).send('Acceso denegado');
    }
});

Asegurarte de que el formulario en el HTML envíe la solicitud como POST:
<form action="/formulario" method="POST">
    <input type="password" name="password">
    <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
</form>

Esto debería resolver el problema.

Use tu solución y nunca entre a agradecerte! me funciono de 10 muchísimas gracias!
